# How to remove and return element in python list

Tags: python, list

In python you can do list.pop(i) which removes and returns the element in index i, but is there a built in function like list.remove(e) where it removes and returns the first element equal to e?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you have `e` already defined, why do you need it to be returned?

Comment: @TidB -- It's the first element _equal_ to `e` -- objects can define their own equality in interesting ways... (whether or not they _should_ is another discussion all together)

Comment: It seems pointless to return `e` from `list.remove(e)` because the return value would just be `e`. Perhaps you'd like something that wouldn't raise a `ValueError` when e` wasn't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I mean, there is [`list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), yes.

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x.remove(1)
>>> x
[2, 3]
```

I don't know why you need it to return the removed element, though. You've already passed it to `list.remove`, so you know what it is... I guess if you've overloaded `__eq__` on the objects in the list so that it doesn't actually correspond to some reasonable notion of equality, you could have problems. But don't do that, because that would be terrible.

If you have done that terrible thing, it's not difficult to roll your own function that does this:

```
def remove_and_return(lst, item):
    return lst.pop(lst.index(item))
```

Comment: To be pedantic, if you do `x.remove(e1)`, `e2` is the removed element it's possible for `e1 == e2` without `e1 is e2`, and therefore you want a particular instance of that element - of course, a system that relies on that is very questionable.

Comment: @sacma This is a valid answer to the question, the answer being that the asked-for functionality shouldn't be needed.

Comment: If it's really necessary to get the value that's in the list, use `list.index()`.

Comment: @sacma "But don't do that, because that would be terrible." That's how this answer addresses the situation you're raising.

Comment: @jpmc26 Are you walking in my profile and criticizing  me?

Comment: @sacma No, I'm going through the Close Queue. O_o I don't know why you'd even think that. As far as I know, this is my first encounter with you.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a builtin?  No.  Probably because if you already know the element you want to remove, then why bother returning it?<sup>1</sup>

The best you can do is get the index, and then pop it.  Ultimately, this isn't such a big deal -- Chaining 2 O(n) algorithms is still O(n), so you still scale roughly the same ...

```
def extract(lst, item):
    idx = lst.index(item)
    return lst.pop(idx)
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>Sure, there are pathological cases where the item returned might not be the item you already know... but they aren't important enough to warrant a new method which takes only 3 lines to write yourself :-)</sup>

Comment: It is, however, worth taking a look at what you are doing and asking if relying on getting a particular instance of an element considered equal to the one you have is a good design idea (it's almost definitely not).

Comment: Also, can I suggest `extract()` as a good name for this method?

Comment: @Lattyware -- Sure you can :-).  And I described the practice of having non-equal equal things as "pathological".  Admittedly, there are (very common) libraries whose objects are subject to this problem.  `numpy.ndarray` instances come to mind immediately... it's a bit sad that concessions needed to be made, but I think that the numpy devs did the right thing here since overriding `==` to return an array really makes the syntax for more common things that you do with numpy a lot nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you would need something like:

```
def remove(lst, e):
    i = lst.index(e)
    # error if e not in lst
    a = lst[i]
    lst.pop(i)
    return a
```

Which would make sense only if `e == a` is true, but `e is a` is false, and you really need `a` instead of `e`.

In most case, though, I would say that this suggest something suspicious in your code.

A short version would be :

```
a = lst.pop(lst.index(e))
```

Comment: `list.pop(i)` returns `a`, so no need to get it separately.

Comment: @Lattyware: I just needed to name the value to compare it to `e` in the explaination

Comment: I see, might want to clarify that in the answer.

Comment: an example where this (strange) condition could hold is it `e` and `a` are `numpy.ndarray` instances.  Of course, this answer doesn't help there because their `__eq__` doesn't return a boolean -- or even something with a non-ambiguous boolean value :-)